# factorized_top_k using tensorflow recommenders

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I followed the tensorflow recommenders [movie ranking tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_ranking) and built the model. Now I would like to get top_k recommendations using the model. This is what I tried:

```
layer = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.Streaming(model.ranking_model)
layer.index(movies.map(model.ranking_model.movie_embeddings), movies)
tracks = layer.query_with_exclusions(
    queries=np.array([["42", "52"]]),
    exclusions= np.array([[]])
)
```

But it throws the error "iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature."

How to invoke the query_with_exclusions() function correctly?